# Example of Linear functional on subspace which cannot have extension

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, examples-counterexamples

I wanted to find example of linear functional on subspace of vector space which cannot be extended to whole vector space.

I know that if we are in normed linear space then extension is always possible also even if we are in vector space with some additional condition on bound using Minkowski functional [By Hanh Banach theorem Analytic form ] we have extension .

I tried to find that but I did not get Any Help will be appreciated
Thanking you

Comment: You got it the other way round.  Algebraically it is always possible to extend (extend a basis of the subspace to the full space and set the functional to 0 on new basis elements), the problem is getting the extension to be continuous.